How does SwiftUI handle multiple Published propery changes?
I have been searching about how SwiftUI redraws views when property values are changed. However, I could not find a good resource that explains how this happens.
Let's say I have a view model and two Published properties. After a method is called, two properties are updated one after each other. Theoretically, each one triggers objectWillChange and SwiftUI redraws the view with the new data. The question is; does SwiftUI draw the view twice or once? I would say it happens once and can also observe this by debugging with Self._printChanges() function. However, I could not find any explanation for this behavior.
How does SwiftUI handle view updates after the properties are changed?
An example;
class ExampleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loading: Bool = true
    @Published var data: String = ""
    
    func load() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3, execute: { [weak self] in
            self?.data = "Data is loaded"
            self?.loading = false
        })
    }
}

struct ExampleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ExampleViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(viewModel.data)
            if viewModel.loading {
                LoadingView()
            }
        }
        .task {
            viewModel.load()
        }
    }
}


WWDC 2021 video Demystify SwiftUI and 2023’s Demystify SwiftUI performance are good primers.

Does this answer your question?

SwiftUI doesn't draw anything. View data struct hierarchy is the view model don't try to use objects instead. Learn state and binding. Return results from your async funcs.

thanks @Sweeper it is a good start point to understand better.

@musakokcen Did you find an answer for that?
